# How to update a form's input text state immediately in React using setState()

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, use-state

```
const [text, setText] = useState('');

const handleTextChange = (e) => {
   setText(e.target.value);
}

// Inside a form
<input onChange={handleTextChange} value={text} type="text" />
```

I'm trying to do something very simple but can't quite get it to work properly. From the code above, I have text and setText to store and update the state, and a function handleTextChange which gets called by the input field's onChange method.

I know that setState() is async so wont update immediately, however, If i need access to the updated result immediately how can I get it? I've read that useEffect hook can be used to do this but I can't figure out how I need to use it. If there is another way to accomplish this then please share.

**The main objective is to get the "updated value of the text state variable" as the user is typing in the input field.**

Comment: `e.target.value` is the immediate value

Comment: I need the value from the text  state variable...

Comment: why? maybe show how you intend to use it?

Comment: check the comment below please...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you can use `e.target.value` for the latest value unless you really want to use a state variable then you can wrap it up in `useEffect` but there does not seem to be a need for it :)

you can just use `disabled={text.length===10}`

Comment: haha..this is exactly where i'm stuck too...I need to check whether the length of the text variable is 10 characters or shorter...so far if i check the length in useEffect it seem does work, however, are there any drawbacks to this approach???

Comment: If i use e.target.value then i'm limited to using it only inside the handleTextChange function...

Comment: as Mulan suggested you can just use e.target.value and get the length from there too right ? 
like const value = e.target.value and then value.length... you don't need to use useEffect in that case

Comment: once the length is 10, what do you plan to do then?

Comment: enable or disable the form submit button...

Comment: yes that's true if you want to access the latest value stored in a state variable then there's no other way than using useEffect

Comment: `<button type="submit" disabled={text.length == 10}>...</button>`

Comment: yep just one note === and not == should work fine

Comment: @Anuj yes that's what i'm thinking too...I think this is the best solution to this problem so far...the useEffect one

Comment: I agree with @Mulan you can just use ```text.length===10```  just one thing double equal sign```==``` does type coercion so it's always recommended to use ```===``` whenever possible

Comment: will this give me the updated text value?? Because the text value is going to be read from the text state variable which won't get updated immediately as far as I can tell

Comment: yep as soon as user will enter something your changeHandler gets called which in turn sets your state and since a state update happened react will re-render your component...in that case it will always have the updated value of the ```text.length```

Comment: if you really want to see it happening you can put a console.log before your ```return``` statement... ```console.log(text.length)```
and you will see it getting disabled once it hits the length you provided

Comment: In the applications current state, If i use the react developer tools to check the state, the value of the text state variable doesnt change immediately if i type quickly...its lags significantly in updating...so im doubtful of this approach, however, I will give it a try to be absolutely sure.

Comment: yeah devtools may take some time to update but I am pretty sure your UI will work just fine

Comment: @Anuj, true `===` is generally preferred, but `.length` always prefers a number so `==` is just as safe in this situation

Answer (score 3):

I don't think `useEffect` is appropriate for what you are trying to do

```js
function App({ onSubmit }) {
  const [text, setText] = React.useState("")
  return <form onSubmit={e => onSubmit(text)}>
    <input
      onChange={e => setText(e.target.value)}
      value={text}
      placeholder="enter a comment"
    />
    <button
      type="submit"
      disabled={text.length >= 10}
      children="disabled at 10 chars"
    />
    <p>{Math.max(0, 10 - text.length)} characters remaining...</p>
  </form>
}

ReactDOM.render(<App onSubmit={alert} />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.14.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.14.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```